# extract value of node that has a namespace declared without a prefix

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml file:

```
<root_tag>
<tag1>
    <tag1_1>A</tag1_1>
    <tag1_2>B</tag1_2>
    <tag1_3>C</tag1_3>
</tag1>
<tag2>
    <tag2_1>D</tag2_1>
    <tag2_2>
        <elem xmlns="http://a.b.com/sample">
            <elem_1>E</elem_1>
            <elem_2>F</elem_2>
        </elem>
    </tag2_2>
</tag2></root_tag>
```

and xslt template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <NODE>
        <node1>
            <xsl:value-of select="/root_tag/tag1/tag1_2"/>
        </node1>
        <node2>
            <xsl:value-of select="/root_tag/tag2/tag2_1"/>
        </node2>
        <node3>
            <xsl:value-of select="/root_tag/tag2/tag2_2/child::*[local-name(.) = 'elem']/child::*[local-name(.) = 'elem_1']"/>
        </node3>
        <xsl:variable name="A" select="namespace-uri(/root_tag/tag2/tag2_2/child::*[local-name(.) = 'elem'])"/>
        <node4>    
            <xsl:value-of select="$A"/>
        </node4>
        <node5>
            <!-- some code here -->
        </node5>
    </NODE>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is:

```
<NODE>
    <node1>B</node1>
    <node2>D</node2>
    <node3>E</node3>
    <node4>http://a.b.com/sample</node4>
    <node5></node5>
</NODE>
```

Is there a way to get in node5 the value of **/root_tag/tag2/tag2_2/elem/elem_1** without using a xpath like the one in node3? Can variable A, that stores the namespace of elem, be somehow used for this?

I also managed to extract the info by adding **xmlns:a_1="http://a.b.com/sample"** in the  **xsl:stylesheet** tag and using the xpath **/root_tag/tag2/tag2_2/a_1:elem/a_1:elem_1**, but this only covers the case when i know the namespace in advance.

Comment: Too bad you're not using XSLT 2.0. You could use `*` for the prefix (example: `*:elem`).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is one way to do this in XSLT 1.0 using the `xxx:node-set()` extension**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfDoc2">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <node5>
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "ext:node-set($vrtfDoc2)/root_tag/tag2/tag2_2/elem/elem_1"/>
  </node5>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root_tag>
    <tag1>
        <tag1_1>A</tag1_1>
        <tag1_2>B</tag1_2>
        <tag1_3>C</tag1_3>
    </tag1>
    <tag2>
        <tag2_1>D</tag2_1>
        <tag2_2>
            <elem xmlns="http://a.b.com/sample">
                <elem_1>E</elem_1>
                <elem_2>F</elem_2>
            </elem>
        </tag2_2>
    </tag2>
</root_tag>
```

**the wanted, correct result (`node5`) is produced:**

```
<node5>E</node5>
```

**Explanation**:

1. This is a *two-pass* transformation.
2. In pass1 the document is transformed into an RTF (Result Tree Fragment) that contains the elements of the original document, but all elements are in "no namespace".
3. The EXSLT `ext:node-set()` extension function is used to convert the RTF obtained in 1. above into a regular tree.
4. The provided XPath expression that doesn't contain any predicates and references to the `local-name()` function, is evaluated against the document that was produced in 3. above.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately - no. Shorter XPath:

```
/root_tag/tag2/tag2_2/*[local-name(.) = 'elem']/*[local-name(.) = 'elem_1']
```